# Draw Text using GeometryDrawing in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I usually use winform based C#, so I guess don't have proper basic concepts of WPF. Can you give me just a simple suggestion how do i draw text on this GeometryDrawing which looks rectangle area?

```
Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.BlueViolet);
brush.Freeze();
Brush penBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
penBrush.Freeze();
Pen pen = new Pen(penBrush, 0.5);
pen.Freeze();

//draw a square with the created brush and pen
System.Windows.Rect r = new System.Windows.Rect(0, 0, 100, 30);
Geometry g = new RectangleGeometry(r);
GeometryDrawing drawing = new GeometryDrawing(brush, pen, g);

drawing.Freeze();

DrawingImage drawingImage = new DrawingImage(drawing);
drawingImage.Freeze();

_image = new Image();
_image.Source = drawingImage;
```

Comment: what exactly you want? do you want to draw rectangle with text in it using wpf ?right?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using GeometryDrawing and DrawingImage? This is not the "typical" way in WPF to put text in a rectangular area.

Comment: This code is a sample code got from MSVS-New Project-Extensibility-Editor Viewport Adorment. I just needed to modify it slightly to draw text on the rectangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very low level api you are trying to use. Normally there are simpler alternatives to place visual with text on your form, but if you are sure you want to get `ImageSource`, this would be the way:

```
var visual = new DrawingVisual();
using (var ctx = visual.RenderOpen())
{

    //rectangle
    ctx.DrawGeometry(brush, pen, r);

    //text
    var text = new FormattedText("Hello world!",
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, typeface, 11, Brushes.Black);
    text.MaxTextWidth = r.Rect.Width;
    text.MaxTextHeight = r.Rect.Height;

    ctx.DrawText(text, r.Rect.TopLeft);
}
RenderTargetBitmap rtv = new RenderTargetBitmap(pixelWidth, pixelHeight, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Default);
rtv.Render(visual);
rtv.Freeze();

_image = new Image();
_image.Source = rtv;
```

Comment: Great, and some idea for a simple example for "typeface" please...?